# How to properly pass struct pointer from C# to C DLL

Tags: c#, c, dllimport

I need to export function from C DLL. Here is example that I have written

```
typedef struct tag_struct {
  unsigned char first;
  unsigned char second;
} st_struct;

__declspec(dllexport) unsigned char Func( st_struct *ptr )
{
    return ptr->first + ptr->second;
}
```

Here is C# code that I'm using to import described above function.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ImportTest
{
    [Serializable]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class st_struct
    {
        public byte first;
        public byte second;
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            st_struct x = new st_struct();

            x.first = 1;
            x.second = 2;

            byte result = Func(ref x);
        }

        [DllImport("MarshalTest.dll")]
        protected static extern byte Func(ref st_struct inputs);
    }
}
```

My problem is that return value of Func is not 3 as it should be (1 + 2).

I am using debugger to see values inside DLL - they are different (not 1 and 2 that I provided).

Function returns proper value whan I change C# code like that:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    st_struct x = new st_struct();

    x.first = 1;
    x.second = 2;

    byte result = Func(x);
}

[DllImport("MarshalTest.dll")]
protected static extern byte Func(st_struct inputs);
```

Problem disappears when I remove ref. But I don't understand why.

Could you please explain that?

Comment: What happens if you use `LayoutKind.Explicit` and decorate the fields with `[FieldOffset(0)]` and `[FieldOffset(1)]`?

Comment: @Theodoros Chatzigiannakis: nothing :(

Comment: What if you try to pass a pointer, instead? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn261468(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What values does the C function see?

Comment: Also, `st_struct` seems like something that should be a struct, not a class.

Comment: @Theodoros Chatzigiannakis: I works correct (when I allocate buffer, copy data to that buffer and pass pointer to function)

Comment: @ Chris: they are different each time

Comment: @walruz Then you're seeing something other in memory. To me, marshalling a class like that doesn't make much sense. Change it to a struct and it should work fine!

Comment: @Chris: you are THE BEST. It is because of class. I made mistake. Could you please write it as answer (not just comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @kennyzx mentions, since your `st_struct` is a class, it is already a reference type and will be passed as a pointer. I suspect throwing a `ref` onto that will give you a double pointer, which doesn't make much sense when mixing managed and unmanaged code. The marshaller can possibly handle that and create a new object for you if the pointer changes, but it seems like a sketchy thing to do.

So, when passing the class without `ref`, it works as expected (the C code gets a pointer). If you change it to a `struct`, passing it without `ref` should pass it on the stack and passing it with `ref` will pass it as a pointer.

Using `struct` seems like the obvious choice in your case, as it can be passed directly (the CLR just needs to pin it and pass a pointer). Using `class` I suspect will involve more marshalling.

Answer (score 2):

You might be thinking that the `ref` keyword is required in order to `passing parameter by reference`. But since `st_struct` is defined as a reference type (class is reference type), so the parameter is passed by reference, not by value. You don't need the `ref` keyword.

If `st_struct` were defined as `struct`, you may find it work when you use the `ref` keyword.